# HTML5 vs W3.org's Validator: Dublin Core (DC.)

Tags: html, metadata, meta-tags, w3c-validation, dublin-core

I have been searching and searching for a way to make the W3.org validator green light my HTML5 developments while including Dublin Core metadata.

This post (on Stack Overflow) asks the question: [Does anyone bother with Dublin Core anymore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648641/does-anyone-bother-with-dublin-core-anymore). And apparently, its time has not yet fully come.

I've also found pages, in varying languages, asking this unanswered question: **How to make it validate?**

So, brains of the internets … How DO you make it valid HTML5 while including DC. metatags?

`<link rel="schema.dc" href="http://purl.org/dc/terms/">` and `<link rel="schema.dc" href="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">` are said to be required on the following links:

- https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions
- http://www.w3.org/wiki/DublinCore

I've also read, that the namespaces of the terms for DC. and DCTERMS. are reserved.

And of course, as you'd no doubt know, the validator itself **Using experimental feature: HTML5 Conformance Checker**.

So, any ideas? Any inside knowledge?

Comment: Thank you, Unor, for reviewing and attending to my typos and grammatical errors :) *highfive!*

Comment: you define `schema.dc twice`. instead it should be 
        `<link rel="schema.DC" href="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" /> <link rel="schema.DCTERMS" href="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually.. you know what? I've just worked something out.

Based on the idea of "If the name spaces for the terms are reserved" and "I wonder what would happen if...", I just removed the link tag. Of course, the error goes away - but low and behold it all seems happy. No Extra Errors! :)

So, that was easier than expected.

Please comment and update this as things change and time progresses.